# Exporting Results of Server Services from a CSV File in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, compare, export-to-csv

I am trying to compare services running on 9 servers which are all supposed to be the same setup but are not currently that way.
I decided to create a script that exports all services from powershell to a csv file so I compare server a to b, a to c, a to d etc...

Each CSV file contains the following columns:  Name, Caption, State, Startmode

I would like to be able to compare the differences and came up with a small powershell script shown below

```
$IWB06 = import-csv C:\PS_Temp\PIN-VUHOIWB06_Services.csv
$IWB09 = import-csv C:\PS_Temp\PIN-VUHOIWB09_Services.csv
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $IWB06 -DifferenceObject $IWB09 -Property 'Unique ID', 'name', 'caption', 'state', 'startmode', 'comparrison' -PassThru -IncludeEqual |
    Format-Table -AutoSize
```

My only issue is that this displays on the powershell console, but I am not able to export the results to a CSV file.

Any suggestion on how to export what is displayed in the console to a CSV file

Comment: does export-csv not work? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6

Comment: Instead of `Format-Table`, just pipe to `Export-Csv`.  If you need both, store the comparison in a variable and run it against both: `$var = compare ..; $var | Format-Table -AutoSize; $var | Export-Csv -Path ..`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Might as well mention `Tee-Object` at this point then since it is very related to that concept.

Comment: @Matt Useful yes, but unfortunately does not send output to two different commands (unless you count Add-Content / New-Variable)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your last line with the following:

```
$Results = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $IWB06 -DifferenceObject $IWB09 -Property 'Unique ID', 'name', 'caption', 'state', 'startmode', 'comparrison' -PassThru -IncludeEqual
$Results | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Unicode -Path C:\temp\MyResult.csv #Replace with your output csv destination
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing two files at a time sounds very inefficient. Why not combine all your CSVs into one object with an additional column denoting the source. You could then use a `Group-Object` to summarise. Something like this:

```
$path = 'C:\PS_Temp\{0}'

(ls *.csv).Name | % {
    $file = $_
    Write-Host $_
    (Import-Csv ($path -f $_)).'Unique ID' | % {
        New-Object psobject -Property @{
            file = $file
            id = $_
        }
    }
} | Group-Object id | % {
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Files -Value ($_.Group.file -Join '|') -PassThru 
} | Select Name, Files, Count
```

This is a simple example just using the unique ID only but you could expand it to include other columns.

Output would be something lik this:

```
Name Files                               Count
---- -----                               -----
3    PIN-VUHOIWB06.csv|PIN-VUHOIWB09.csv     2
4    PIN-VUHOIWB06.csv|PIN-VUHOIWB09.csv     2
5    PIN-VUHOIWB06.csv|PIN-VUHOIWB09.csv     2
6    PIN-VUHOIWB06.csv|PIN-VUHOIWB09.csv     2
7    PIN-VUHOIWB06.csv                       1
8    PIN-VUHOIWB06.csv                       1
9    PIN-VUHOIWB06.csv                       1
1    PIN-VUHOIWB09.csv                       1
2    PIN-VUHOIWB09.csv                       1
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your code:

```
$comparison = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $IWB06 -DifferenceObject $IWB09 -Property 'Unique ID', 'name', 'caption', 'state', 'startmode', 'comparrison' -PassThru -IncludeEqual |


$comparison | Export-CSV -path $someFullPath
```